# Boost.ASIO UDP socket: sink all the packets

Tags: c++, boost, udp, buffer, boost-asio

I'm using the boost::asio::ip::udp::socket to receive UDP packets via socket's async_receive_from method.

The code works fine, the only problem is that in the time I process a packet, lots more come creating a queue (the buffer) to process. My program though must sink all the packets received since the start of the processing, so that it listens only to the most recent ones.

Example:

- packet 1 is sent
- packet 1 is being processed
- packets 2, 3, 4 are sent
- packet 1 ends the computation
- **flush the buffer**
- packet 5 is sent
- packet 5 is being processed
- etc

Is there any way to discard the packets in the middle?
Thanks!

Comment: You have to store and order your packets before you process them. For example you could add them to a list and then process this list from the back.

Comment: Thanks user743414. I currently do it via the buffer. What I don't want is to process "old" packets, I just want to process as many packets I can, discarding the ones in the middle.

Comment: Define "old" packet? Are you using a timestamp or a simple up counting id? When you just want to process the last packet, then you just have to store the last received packet.

Comment: Nope, nothing of it, they are just commands that overwrite themselves. I need to process only the last one, because otherwise I'd create a delay. I don't need to process the packets in the middle. And I can't specify a buffer's minimum size as packets have different sizes

Comment: Is the processing of packet 1 on the sender or receiver?

Comment: The processing is on the receiver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use a buffer that holds only a single datagram.
2. Keep reading into the buffer until there are no more datagrams to read.
3. If you read at least one packet, process the datagram in the buffer.
4. Go to step 2.

Note that UDP is a datagram protocol, not a packet protocol. A single UDP datagram can be split over multiple packets.

Comment: Thanks David. Unfortunately the datagram size varies from command to command, so I can't make a size-tailored buffer. What I may do though is to asynchronously listen for UDP datagrams, parse the received bytes (buffer is big enought to get the heavier datagram) and eventually receive synchronously, non-blocking till I have no bytes to read anymore... would this work?

Comment: @Jack Don't make a size-tailored buffer for something that's only going to be around for a short amount of time. Just use a fixed sized buffer. If it happens later that you need to keep the object for a longer period of time, copy it into a right-sized buffer.

Comment: Hello David. I think I misunderstand your first point then: "Use a buffer that holds only a single datagram" - what did you mean?

Comment: @Jack I mean one buffer that holds one datagram.

Comment: I've resolved making a mix of async / sync: at the first async message received, process it and read any data received in the mean while setting the socket as non-blocking, synchronously reading the data until the buffer contains data, then set the socket back to blocking and call the async listen method again.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be done quite simple:

1. `async_receive_from` until got a packet.
2. Check `available` method to determine is more data in the socket.
3. If we have more data, discard buffer and goto 1; else process packet

Comment: Hello PSIAlt, thanks for the answer. I saw the available method and I was thinking about discarding the buffer, but I wasn't able to do it. How'd you discard the buffer?

Comment: @Jack its not possible, sockets API does not have this function. You only can read the data and do nothing.